# Glycemic load for foods with respect to dogs

Tags: dogs, diet, biology, diabetes, digestion

Have there ever been conducted tests on how fast dogs digest various foods? That is, to determine the glycemic load of various foods with respect to dogs?

Comment: It should be roughly similar to humans. Starches are high. Meats are low.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but **it's complicated**. The [glycemic index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycemic_index) of dog foods depends on various variables, like which carbohydrates are contained in it and how much fiber and which type(s) of fiber the food contains.

[This study](https://academic.oup.com/jas/article-abstract/98/8/skaa241/5889930) compared the glycemic indices of different dog foods with starches from different sources:

> The GI [glycemic index] (±SE) [standard error] of the single starch sources and dog foods was: white bread: 47 ± 11, cooked white rice: 71 ± 14, cooked green lentils: 60 ± 20 (P = 0.569), traditional grain: 83 ± 17, whole grain: 56 ± 8, grain-free: 41 ± 6, and vegan: 65 ± 15 (P = 0.154). No statistical differences in glycemic response over time were observed between the single starch sources or the extruded diets tested (P = 0.1412; P = 0.2651). The insulinemic response elicited by the extruded diets was also not different (P = 0.079); however, the traditional grain diet did have the slowest time to peak for insulin (P = 0.0078).

[This study](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1439-0396.2007.00794.x) also compared how fast different starches raised the blood sugar level:

> Dogs’ immediate post‐prandial glucose and insulin responses (AUC ≤ 30 min) were greater for brewer’s rice, corn, and cassava flour diets (p < 0.05), and later meal responses (AUC ≥ 30 min) were greater for sorghum, lentil and pea diets (p < 0.05).

[This study](https://harvest.usask.ca/handle/10388/8471) even compared the metabolism of carbohydrates in cats and dogs:

> Two studies were designed to determine the research objectives:
>
> • Determine species metabolic differences (dog versus cat) to both low and high glycemic index carbohydrate sources, and link these to postprandial cardiovascular and methylglyoxal results;
>
> and
>
> • Compare long-term health benefits of diets formulated with pulse starch to a modified cornstarch diet in dogs versus cats, including digestibility, glycemic, insulinemic, and cardiovascular responses, and postprandial methylglyoxal levels.

It found no significant differences in how cats and dogs metabolize carbohydrates.

[Another study](https://europepmc.org/article/med/1665025) looked at different fiber contents of dog food and measured the effects on diabetic dogs.

> Mean postprandial plasma glucose concentration measured every 2 hours for 24 hours, beginning at the time of the morning insulin injection, was significantly (P less than 0.05) lower at most blood sampling times in dogs fed IF [diet containing 15%  insoluble-fiber] and SF [diet containing 15%  soluble-fiber] diets, compared with dogs fed the LF [low-fiber] diet.